# Since upgrading to ermine, getting an error on login

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I updated to Ermine from Dingo yesterday, and since then I've been getting the following message when I log in

```
System monitor extension
Dependencies missing
Please install
lipgtop, Network Manager and gir bindings
On Ubuntu: gir1.2-gtop-2.0, gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
```

But, when I try to update these from the command line, it's saying the latest release is already installed. Can you help?

Comment: Any news about this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: no, nothing. Apart from the error message on login, I haven't noticed any other issues running the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing Gnome tweaks and disabling the "Launch system monitor" and "System-monitor" options on the Extensions tab